# How to get the COUNT of this mySQL query?

Tags: mysql

How can I just get the number of rows on the below query?

```
select
hash,page,timestamp, count(*) as total
from behaviour
group by hash,page
having total > 2 AND timestamp >= Now() - interval 5 minute
```

Comment: `SELECT FOUND_ROWS();` after that would return the total if thats what your asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution by just querying:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
select
hash,page,timestamp, count(*) as total
from behaviour
group by hash,page
having total > 2 AND timestamp >= Now() - interval 5 minute) AS t1
```

Comment: any solution without using php ?

Comment: I have this error: Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Edited my answer, i forgot to add an alias to the table. Try again please